# Extract Specific Values in a JSON String using XSLT

Tags: json, xslt, xslt-1.0, bpel

I need help in getting the specific keys and its dynamic values stored in JSON string in an XML element.

Below is an example of the JSON data:

```
<data attribute-id="item">
[
  {
    "item_name": "item1",
    "quantity": 1,
    "key": "subtotal",
    "price": {
      "currency": "CAD",
      "amount": 123.75,
      "label": "320.088,75 CAD",
      "base": {
        "amount": 34.75,
        "currency": "USD",
        "label": "US$90.75"
      }
    },
    "total": {
      "currency": "CAD",
      "amount": 123.75,
      "label": "320.088,75 CAD",
      "base": {
        "amount": 90.75,
        "currency": "USD",
        "label": "US$90.75"
      }
    },
    "included": [
      {
        "key": "item_price",
        "total": {
          "currency": "CAD",
          "amount": 123,
          "label": "376.575,00 CAD",
          "base": {
            "amount": 106.76,
            "currency": "USD",
            "label": "US$106.76"
          }
        },
        "price": {
          "currency": "CAD",
          "amount": 123,
          "label": "376.575,00 CAD",
          "base": {
            "amount": 106.76,
            "currency": "USD",
            "label": "US$106.76"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "rounding",
        "total": {
          "currency": "CAD",
          "amount": 0,
          "label": "0,00 CAD",
          "base": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD",
            "label": "US$0.00"
          }
        },
        "price": {
          "currency": "CAD",
          "amount": 0,
          "label": "0,00 CAD",
          "base": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD",
            "label": "US$0.00"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "item_discount",
        "total": {
          "currency": "CAD",
          "amount": -56486.25,
          "label": "-56.486,25 CAD",
          "base": {
            "amount": -16.01,
            "currency": "USD",
            "label": "-US$16.01"
          }
        },
        "price": {
          "currency": "CAD",
          "amount": -56486.25,
          "label": "-56.486,25 CAD",
          "base": {
            "amount": -16.01,
            "currency": "USD",
            "label": "-US$16.01"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item_name": "item2",
    "quantity": 2,
    "key": "subtotal",
    "price": {
      "currency": "CAD",
      "amount": 14343.75,
      "label": "320.088,75 CAD",
      "base": {
        "amount": 90.75,
        "currency": "USD",
        "label": "US$90.75"
      }
    },
    "total": {
      "currency": "CAD",
      "amount": 3431.5,
      "label": "640.177,50 CAD",
      "base": {
        "amount": 181.5,
        "currency": "USD",
        "label": "US$181.50"
      }
    },
    "included": [
      {
        "key": "item_price",
        "total": {
          "currency": "CAD",
          "amount": 753150,
          "label": "753.150,00 CAD",
          "base": {
            "amount": 213.52,
            "currency": "USD",
            "label": "US$213.52"
          }
        },
        "price": {
          "currency": "CAD",
          "amount": 376575,
          "label": "376.575,00 CAD",
          "base": {
            "amount": 106.76,
            "currency": "USD",
            "label": "US$106.76"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "rounding",
        "total": {
          "currency": "CAD",
          "amount": 0,
          "label": "0,00 CAD",
          "base": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD",
            "label": "US$0.00"
          }
        },
        "price": {
          "currency": "CAD",
          "amount": 0,
          "label": "0,00 CAD",
          "base": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD",
            "label": "US$0.00"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "item_discount",
        "total": {
          "currency": "CAD",
          "amount": -112972.5,
          "label": "-112.972,50 CAD",
          "base": {
            "amount": -32.02,
            "currency": "USD",
            "label": "-US$32.02"
          }
        },
        "price": {
          "currency": "CAD",
          "amount": -56486.25,
          "label": "-56.486,25 CAD",
          "base": {
            "amount": -16.01,
            "currency": "USD",
            "label": "-US$16.01"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
</data>
```

My Expected output is to get key "item_name" and its dynamic value and key "amount" and its dynamic value  (key->discount (base array)). Below is the expected output from the given JSON string:

```
"item_name": "item1","base": {
            "amount": -16.01,
            "currency": "USD",
            "label": "-US$16.01"
          },
          "item_name": "item2","base": {
            "amount": -32.02,
           "currency": "USD",
          "label": "-US$32.02"
     }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: XSLT 1.0 does not have any built-in tools to deal with JSON. It can extract the *entire* JSON from the XML, but then you need to use something else to deal with the JSON. What other tools do you have available (programming language/command line)?

Comment: Hi Tomalak! Will it work for higher XSLT stylesheet version?

Comment: The first XSLT version that comes with JSON support is XSLT 3.0 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#json). What XSLT processor are you using, exactly?

Comment: I am using XSLT transformation in BPEL.

Comment: That still does not say anything about which XSLT processor is being used. But realistically, if it does not advertise anywhere that it supports XSLT 3.0, chances are high that 1.0 is the only supported version.

Comment: Since BPEL supports JavaScript, maybe you could use XPath to extract the JSON and then JS to get the value you need?